# invalid or missing options

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, xdebug

I am trying to create an XDebug UI for my editor and so far I cannot run any command successfully. Each time I run a command, I get `invalid or missing options`. After reading the docs multiple times, I cannot see what argument I am really missing. Here is the output of the XDebug I get:

```
22:06:52: RUN CALLED
22:06:58: Got connection from 127.0.0.1:52005
22:06:58: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/wamp/www/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="4752" idekey="studio">
    <engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine>
    <author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author>
    <url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url>
    <copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright>
</init>

22:06:58: SENT COMMAND:breakpoint_set  -i 1  -f file:///C:/wamp/www/index.php -n 248 -t line
22:06:58: SENT COMMAND:run  -i 2
22:06:58: SENT COMMAND:breakpoint_list  -i 3

22:06:58: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set">
    <error code="3">
        <message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message>
    </error>
</response>

22:06:58: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run">
    <error code="3">
        <message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message>
    </error>
</response>

22:06:58: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list">
    <error code="3">
        <message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message>
    </error>
</response>
```

Comment: there was multiple spaces in command. Thanks to @derrickrethans in mailing list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all three cases, you seem to have an extra space before the `-i x`, and for the breakpoint_set, one after `-i 1` too. You shouldn't do that. If that doesn't fix it, you might have some other random characters, which I can't see from your post.